# Outlook Add-in REST API deprecation

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

We are retrieving the email and attachments using the oAuth token from `getCallbackTokenAsync` in [office.js](https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js) JavaScript library and sending the token to the web application to retrieve them from EWS (`~/EWS/Exchange.asmx`) using SOAP request similar to the approach shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item

1. Could anyone please confirm that the deprecation of Outlook Rest API 2.0 will not affect the existing functionality. I am new to the Outlook add-in development and the documentation seems vast to digest.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/outlook-rest-api-v2-0-deprecation-notice/

2. Do we need to register the add-in anywhere OR provide any permissions to the add-in specifically for `getCallbackTokenAsync` method to retrieve the token OR making the SOAP request to download attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS remains unchanged for Outlook web add-ins. Make sure that you don't use the `isRest` option for the `getCallbackTokenAsync` call.

Take a look at the recent [Office add-ins community call](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O47gN9P8KAI) where this question was discussed in depth. Here is a screenshot for others:

[image: REST API decomissioned]

Comment: Thank you. Do we need to set any permissions/register the add-in.

Comment: Nope. EWS continue working as is now. See the video referenced for more information.